# How do I clear my Bash history in OS X?

Tags: bash

How do I clear my [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) history in Mac OS X?

I've entered a few "errors" and just want to clear them off. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

To clear it, just delete the `~/.bash_history` file. If you want to just remove the offending lines you can open `~/.bash_history` in the editor of your choice. For me, this would be

```
emacs ~/.bash_history
```

and then going to the beginning of each bad line and pressing <kbd>control ^</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Or your can just fill your `.bash_history` with empty.
Run this: (including the `>`)

```
 > ~/.bash_history
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run:

```
history -c
```

I use it often, so I made an alias to `hc`.

Comment: Just to note, this works for clearing history from the current shell while my answer is for sessions that have already been closed.

Answer (score 2):

To view your bash history enter the command:

```
history
```

You will get an index of your history.

You can clear your entire history like so:

```
history -c
```

You can clear the 45th item in your history like so:

```
history -d 45
```

(get you can see the history item numbers by executing the `history` command)